Why exactly are badnesses squared in the calculation of demerits?
As Chapter 14 of the TeXbook says, the demerit d of a line is defined by the formula
d = (l + b)² + p², if 0 ≤ p < 10000;
    (l + b)² - p², if -10000 < p < 0;
    (l + b)²,      if p ≤ -10000.

where l is \linepenalty, b is the badness of the line, and p is the penalty associated with the breakpoint at the end of the line.
But why exactly is the badness squared?
In Chapter 2, Mathematical Typography of Digital Typography, Knuth says:

The line division problem may now be stated as follows. “Given
the text of a paragraph and the set of all allowable places to break it between lines, find breakpoints that minimize the sum of the squares of the badnesses of the resulting lines.” This definition is quite arbitrary, of course, but it seems to work. Preliminary experiments show that the same choice of breakpoints is almost always found when simply minimizing the sum of the individual badnesses rather than the sum of their squares, but it seems wise to minimize the sum of squares as a precautionary measure since this will also tend to minimize the maximum badness.

This I understand: for example, the sequences of badnesses (2, 2) and (1, 3) are equally bad if you simply sum the individual badnesses, since 2 + 2 = 1 + 3; but if you sum the squares of the badnesses, (2, 2) is better than (1, 3), since 22 + 22 < 12 + 32.
However, in Chapter 3, Breaking Paragraphs Into Lines, Knuth and Plass go on to say (emphasis mine):

The formula for δj [the demerit of the jth line] is quite arbitrary, like our formula for βj [the badness of the jth line], but it works well in practice because it has the following desirable properties: (a) Minimizing the sum of squares of badnesses not only tends to minimize the maximum badness per line, it also provides secondary optimization; for example, when one particularly bad line is inevitable, the other line breaks will also be optimized. …

This I don't understand. If the "particularly bad line" is "inevitable", wouldn't its badness be included in any possible sequence of badnesses, and thus be an ignorable constant whether it's squared or not? How exactly does the "secondary optimization" work?

It's conventional to minimize the sum of squares. I'm not really sure why least-squares is so common in general, but I think that it has a few nice mathematical properties.

With +1 to Udo Wermuth's answer, elaborating in a slightly different way on what I take to be your core question: for choosing between using the sum of squares of badnesses instead of just the sum of badnesses, isn't it the case that one inevitable bad line is equivalent in both cases?
Firstly, let me say that you're looking at the right sources:

The TeXbook (1984),
Knuth's 1978 Gibbs lecture for AMS titled Mathematical Typography, reprinted with corrections as Chapter 2 of the collection Digital Typography,
The 1981 paper Breaking Paragraphs into Lines by Knuth and Plass (what he considered the main research output of the TeX project), reprinted with corrections as Chapter 3 of Digital Typography.

In the part you quoted from the second source (Chapter 2), he's saying that using the sum of squares of badnesses (let's call it quadratic sum) is better than using just the sum of badnesses (let's call it linear sum), as this also minimizes the maximum badness: like the example you gave, of (2, 2) and (3, 1) being equally bad under the linear sum, but (2, 2) being better under the quadratic sum. Taking it further, an example where they differ is that (2, 2) is better than (3, 0) under the quadratic sum, but worse under the linear sum — though (3, 0) has a smaller sum, (2, 2) minimizes the maximum badness.
However, in the part that you quoted from the third source (Chapter 3), the context is different! On the previous page, he compares the two greedy algorithms “first-fit” and “best-fit” for their tightest and loosest lines, before presenting TeX's “total-fit” algorithm. That is, here he's looking at which algorithm minimizes the maximum badness. It is in this context that he says:

Minimizing the sum of squares of badnesses not only tends to minimize the maximum badness per line, it also provides secondary optimization; for example, when one particularly bad line is inevitable, the other line breaks will also be optimized.

To reiterate, in this context what is being compared is not “sum of squares of badnesses” versus “sum of badnesses”, but simply “sum of squares of badnesses” versus “the maximum badness”.
To state the same thing from another point of view, we can consider the problem as being that of finding breakpoints such that: the largest badness is minimized, among solutions with the same largest badness the second-largest badness is minimized, etc. (If we're going to write down the list of the badnesses of the lines in non-increasing order, then we want to find the breakpoints that result in the lexicographically smallest list.) Using an "nth-power sum" with very large n would achieve this, and n=2 is "good enough" (and better than n=1). For example, (5, 2, 2) is better than (5, 3, 0) by this measure [secondary optimization], and if we only minimized the maximum badness they would be equivalent, and if we minimized the sum of badnesses then 5+3+0 < 5+2+2, but using the sum of squares of badnesses, 5²+2²+2² < 5²+3²+0². (Of course it's possible to construct examples where cubes would be even better—for example, (3, 3) is better than (4, 1)—but the examples get increasingly artificial and unlikely to occur as line-breaks' badnesses, and cubes require arithmetic with larger numbers, so 2 is good enough.)

Thank you, and +1 for your answer. Although I think the ℓ²-norm is not a good term. First, it's rather technical, second as a norm it implies to take the square root of the sum of squares.

Thank you! I'm choosing this as the accepted answer because it points out my core misunderstanding of the third source.

@UdoWermuth Oh good point; thanks for pointing that out — even worse than using needlessly technical terms is using them incorrectly. :-) I just wanted something shorter than repeating "sum of squares of badnesses" each time (and also to refer to higher powers); replaced with "linear sum", "quadratic sum", "nth-power sum".

As the cited text states the formula is an invention of the
author. Its quality is based on experience although there are some
theoretical insights for the general structure. As a large badness
becomes worse when squared, lines with a large badness are unlikely to
be compensated by a few of, say, perfect lines: Between a badness of
40 and 50 you have a difference (with \linepenalty) of 60^2 - 50^2 =
1100 demerits.
As you said (2,2) turns now out to be better than (1,3) as the lines
look more uniform. Or make it more realistic: two loose lines, say
(20,20), look better than a pair lines with (0,40). (If (20,20) is a
pair of a tight and a loose line \adjdemerits are charged. But that is
another story.) In general, the expectation is, that a very bad line
is avoided if possible as its squared badness becomes so much higher
than the badness of a normal or a bad line. That's what the author
means when he states that the maximum badness is minimized.
Why squares? Obviously it does what is expected, otherwise you can
also take the cube as it is done for the badness itself. But squares
are faster to compute than cubes and need a smaller maximum.
Now to the secondary optimization. (Note, the demerits formula in the
Knuth and Plass paper is different from the one in The TeXbook.) Yes
you are right, if a bad line is part of every line breaking then it
can be considered a constant. Nevertheless, TeX picks the paragraph
that optimizes the other lines, i.e., the optimization of the other
lines of the paragraph is still there.
Now let's assume that TeX needs to typeset a very bad line, say, with
badness 200 in the second pass. It might have a choice between two
lines, say line 2 and line 3, but one of them must receive a badness
of 200 in all acceptable line-breaking sets. TeX selects from the two
lines the one that gives the smaller demerits for the rest of the
paragraph. It doesn't select line 2 only because it is the first with
the high badness.
With overfull lines the situation is different. TeX optimizes the
paragraph up to the overfull line and then it restarts the line-breaking procedure.
